# ES6 classes with Angular 1 DI issue with $inject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

```
class Foo {
    constructor(dep1) {
    }
}
Foo.$inject = ['Dependency1']
```

I know you can do DI like this in angular /w es6 classes. However, I need to also pass something into my constructor for foo (a config object). This is eluding me because from my knowledge, the DI parameters go first.

Essentially, I want to do

```
let foo = new Foo(config); //config defined above
```

But still have the benefits of the injectable dependencies in the class.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
let angular = window.angular;
class Foo{
    constructor(config){
        let injector = angular.injector();
        let dep1 = injector.get('Dependency1');
        this.prop1 = config.prop;
        this.prop2 = dep1.get(); 
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
//assuming ES6 modules, export dependency as module
import dependency from 'path';
class Foo{
    constructor(config){
        this.prop1 = config.prop;
        this.prop2 = dependency.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use Foo as an angular service?

Comment: slowly moving off of angular 1 to angular 2, with es6 as a step in between